# É possível fazer com que uma linha do repeater não repita ? c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

É possível fazer com que uma linha do repeater não repita ? Ou dar um bind em umas linhas do `FooterTemplate` do `Repeater` ?
Preciso que a ultima linha que eu tentei colocar no FooterTemplate não repita, pois são os valores totais. 
Quando eu deixo no `ItemTemplate` ele exibe 3 vezes de acordo com o numero de linhas que o `datatable` possui.

Era pra ficar assim:
[image: Era pra ficar assim]

Porém, quando eu coloco no FooterTemplate fica assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código:

//ASPX

```
<FooterTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="tbFundoColVazia">
            <b>
                <asp:Label ID="Label46" class="fontlbl" runat="server" Text="Totais"></asp:Label></b>
        </td>
        <td id="colCompraQtdeTotais" style="font-weight: bold" class="tbFundoColVazia">
            <%# Eval("qtdTotalCompra") %>
        </td>
        <td id="colCompraValorTotais" style="font-weight: bold" class="tbFundoColVazia">
            <%# string.Format("{0:C}", Eval("valorTotalCompra")).Replace("R$", "") %>
        </td>
        <td id="colDevolucaoQtdeTotais" style="font-weight: bold" class="tbFundoColVazia">
            <%# Eval("qtdTotalDevolucao") %>
        </td>
        <td id="colDevolucaoValorTotais" style="font-weight: bold" class="tbFundoColVazia">
            <%# string.Format("{0:C}", Eval("valorTotalDevolucao")).Replace("R$", "") %>
        </td>
        <td id="colRetornoQtdeTotais" style="font-weight: bold" class="tbFundoColVazia">
            <%# Eval("qtdTotalRetorno") %>
        </td>
        <td id="colRetornoQValorTotais" style="font-weight: bold" class="tbFundoColVazia">
            <%# string.Format("{0:C}", Eval("valorTotalRetorno")).Replace("R$", "") %>
        </td>
        <td id="colVendaQtdeTotais" style="font-weight: bold" class="tbFundoColVazia">
            <%# Eval("qtdTotalVenda") %>
        </td>
        <td id="colVendaValorTotais" style="font-weight: bold" class="tbFundoColVazia">
            <%# string.Format("{0:C}", Eval("valorTotalVenda")).Replace("R$", "") %>
        </td>
        <td id="colDoacaoQtdeTotais" style="font-weight: bold" class="tbFundoColVazia">
            <%# Eval("qtdTotalDoacao") %>
        </td>
        <td id="colDoacaoValorTotais" style="font-weight: bold" class="tbFundoColVazia">
            <%# string.Format("{0:C}", Eval("valorTotalDoacao")).Replace("R$", "") %>
        </td>
        <td id="colReenvioQtdeTotais" style="font-weight: bold" class="tbFundoColVazia">
            <%# Eval("qtdTotalReenvio") %>
        </td>
        <td id="colReenvioValorTotais" style="font-weight: bold" class="tbFundoColVazia">
            <%# string.Format("{0:C}", Eval("valorTotalReenvio")).Replace("R$", "") %>
        </td>
    </tr>
</FooterTemplate>
```

Comment: Você não pode deixar a ultima linha fora do loop?

Comment: @Willian Então, eu já deixei só que não preenche essa ultima linha de acordo com o que precisa com o que eu joguei pra dar o Bind

Comment: Tem como você mostrar como está aparecendo e como deveria aparecer? Tipo imagens, mesmo que sejam com dados fictícios?

Comment: Pronto @Willian, teria que ficar igual a primeira imagem.

Comment: Os valores totais são calculados em qual momento? Você chegou a verificar se as chamadas de "ValorTotalCompra" e etc está retornando os valores?

Comment: @Willian, sim, estão retornando valores, eles são carregados no momento em que eu chamo o método que retorna pro datasource do repeater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu não sei e nunca utilizei `Eval` dentro do `FooterTemplate`. Você pode criar um  método no seu código para calcular a soma das colunas do `DataTable` e chamar no `Repeater`

```
  protected decimal Total(string campo)
  {
            return Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Compute($"Sum({campo})", string.Empty));
  }
```

Assim:

```
<FooterTemplate>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%# Total("colCompraQtde") %></td>
                        <td><%# Total("colCompraValor") %></td>
                        <td><%# Total("colDevolucaoQtde") %></td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
</FooterTemplate>
```

Exemplo completo ASPX:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptVendas" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                      <th></th>
                      <th></th>
                      <th></th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
              <tr class="cor1">
                  <td><%# Eval("colCompraQtde") %></td>
                  <td><%# Eval("colCompraValor") %></td>
                  <td><%# Eval("colDevolucaoQtde") %></td>
              </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                <tr class="cor2">
                    <td><%# Eval("colCompraQtde") %></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("colCompraValor") %></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("colDevolucaoQtde") %></td>
               </tr>
            </AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                 </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%# Total("colCompraQtde") %></td>
                        <td><%# Total("colCompraValor") %></td>
                        <td><%# Total("colDevolucaoQtde") %></td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
               </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

C#

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private DataTable dt;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("colCompraQtde", typeof(decimal));
            dt.Columns.Add("colCompraValor", typeof(decimal));
            dt.Columns.Add("colDevolucaoQtde", typeof(decimal));

            dt.Rows.Add(1, 5, 0);
            dt.Rows.Add(1, 2.5, 0);
            dt.Rows.Add(1, 3, 0);

            rptVendas.DataSource = dt;
            rptVendas.DataBind();
        }

        protected decimal Total(string campo)
        {
            return Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Compute($"Sum({campo})", string.Empty));
        }

    }
```